# Hi I am trying to build a JavaFx Gui and JVM always crashes with this bug report

Tags: jvm

I do not understand what the bug report means. If someone can help me understand the issue and tell me about any possible fix I can try. It will be super helpful. I posted as much of the report I can and thought was useful. Why would this happen? what is the fix?

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4325164097, pid=62906, tid=62956
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.8+9) (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x564097]  ClassLoaderData::ChunkedHandleList::oops_do(OopClosure*)+0x57
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /media/dirtyvoid/FileHub/Universal_Data/Codes/Java/A_project/core.62906)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

if anyone interested the full core dump can be found here: https://pastebin.com/JMP73PgD

I would post the code but the code is super simple and I feel has nothing to do with the issue.
If anyone one wants the code, please comment, I will make the github link available. (I know SO hates github link and prefers minimum reproducible code but I have no idea which part of the code makes it crash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like g1 garbage collector does not work well with small heaps and linux for some reason.
using `-XX:+UseParallelGC` has stopped my code from crashing.

```
java -XX:+UseParallelGC -p $jfx_path --add-modules $jfx_modules -cp $classpath Main
```

Comment: I doubt that it has anything to do with G1, small heaps, or Linux. Did you try a newer JDK? Did you file a bug report?

Comment: I downloaded `17.0.8 javac` from Oracle. I did not file a bug report since using parallel gc fixed it. it does not crash anymore.